# Using React Hooks reference with Class and Function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been out of the React game for awhile. Come back and I'm trying to implement the Material UI library which has been rewritten with Hooks.

It seems to be extremely confusing + spagetti code in my eyes.

I simply want to reference a function so I can toggle the drawer, how can I do this?

```
// Old class
export default class DefaultContainer extends Component<ViewProps, any> {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>

                <MainAppBar
                    onPress={() => this.onMenuPressed()}
                />

                {this.props.children}

                <MainDrawer
                    ref={'drawer'}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    onMenuPressed = () => {
       // TODO The bit that isn't working
       (this.refs['drawer'] as Drawer).handleToggle()
    }
}
```

Now the new material UI drawer

```
// New Drawer (3x more code now..)
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    list: {
        width: 280,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
    },
})

type Props = {
}

function MainDrawer(props: Props, ref: any) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        left: false,
    });

    const toggleDrawer = () => (
        event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent,
    ) => {
        if (
            event.type === 'keydown' &&
            ((event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Tab' ||
                (event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Shift')
        ) {
            return;
        }

        setState({ ...state, left: true });
    };

    const inputRef = useRef();
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        toggleDrawer()
    });

    const sideList = () => (
        <div
            className={classes.list}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer()}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer()}
        >
            <List>
                <ListItem button key={'drawer_item'}>
                    <ListItemIcon><GroupIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={'Test Item'} />
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={toggleDrawer()}>Open Left</Button>
            <Drawer open={state.left} onClose={toggleDrawer()}>
                {sideList()}
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default forwardRef(MainDrawer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand why you need to invoke a function from inside `MainDrawer` rather than just leveraging the use of `props` e.g.

**Container**

```
export default function DefaultContainer(props: ViewProps) {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = React.useState(false);
  // assuming it's a toggle?
  const toggleMenu = React.useCallback(() => setDrawerOpen(open => !open));
  return (
    <View>
        <MainAppBar onPress={toggleMenu} />
        {this.props.children}
        <MainDrawer open={drawerOpen} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

**MainDrawer**

```
function MainDrawer(props: Props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.open);
  ...
  const toggleDrawer = React.useCallback(() => setOpen(open => !open));
  return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer}>Open Left</Button>
        // use prop to determine whether drawer is open or closed
        <Drawer open={open} onClose={toggleDrawer}>
          {sideList()}
        </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I do this I get an error saying hooks cannot be used outside of a function. It's a large project with many existing components; I need to convert them all to functions now?

Comment: @OliverDixon sounds like you are attempting to use a hook in a class component? I've converted your `DefaultContainer` over to a function component. It shouldn't have much affect on anything doing that, however, if you need it to stay a class then you can just adjust to suit the state management.

Comment: @OliverDixon no you are trying to mix a class component with a function component (which is fine), you 100% *cannot* use hooks in a class component, my code does not do that so the error you are getting can't be using the code as written.

Comment: What would the example look like if the DefaultContainer was a class?

Comment: @OliverDixon much the same as your original class, only leveraging `setState` rather than trying to call a function in your nested component. Is there some reason you can't use the converted function component in the example? If the code you have shown is complete then it should be a like for like swap out

Comment: btw this causes an error. ```props.open``` is immutable. ```toggleDrawer``` inside MainDrawer fails. Unless I'm missing something? Urg classes were so much easier to read.

Comment: @OliverDixon fails in what way? I'm not sure I see anywhere I'm mutating `props.open`, sounds like a TS error, what line is that?

Comment: Well because the prop.open doesn't change from within the drawer function (component, what do you call it now?). So it never changes from the default container. Even subscribing with the deps does nothing. I had to use an effect to update it and subscribe with a dep [props.open]. The whole process seems cumbersum and less readable instead of just calling a func via a ref with 1 line. Where is the state stored? This is awful.

Comment: @OliverDixon but `props` [should be read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) so I'm a little confused about the warning/error regarding that. From the sounds of what you are doing that does sound convoluted and definitely shouldn't be that complicated, in my answer it should be pretty simple - pass props down into the component to control the open/close state from external components. Track the open/close state internally to manage it from internal.

Comment: One _slight_ oversight is the fact the external state & internal state are independent of eachother and therefore could get out of sync e.g. open drawer from `MainAppBar`, close drawer from `MainDrawer` and then try to re-open from `MainAppBar` (I'd expect nothing to happen on first click as the state is already closed). You may need to look at possibly using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share the state across these components